# How do I display the hosts inside the Google Chrome sqlite3 "cookie" database using Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, cookies, sqlite

I'm using Python to access the "cookie" chrome sqlite3 db to retrieve the host keys, but getting error below

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(r"C:\Users\tikka\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies")
cursor  = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select host_key from cookies")
results = cursor.fetchall()
print results
conn.close()
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\cookies.py", line 4, in <module>
    cursor.execute("select host_key from cookies")
DatabaseError: malformed database schema (is_transient) - near "where": syntax error
>>>
```

Comment: Looks related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31652864/sqlite3-error-malformed-database-schema-is-transient-near-where-syntax-e. And this also: http://www.obsidianforensics.com/blog/upgrading-python-sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

thanks to [link](http://www.obsidianforensics.com/blog/upgrading-python-sqlite) provided by [alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe) was able to fix it by upgrading sqlite3 version from 3.6.21 to 3.9.2. I upgraded by downloading [new version](https://www.sqlite.org/2015/sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3090200.zip) from [this site](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) and placing the dll in  C:\Python27\DLLs